# Trying to connect oracle DB to c++

Tags: c++, oracle

I'm trying to connect to oracle DB but am getting undefined errors. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct ShoppingCart {
    int product_id;
    double price;
    int quantity;
};

int main() {

    Environment* env = nullptr;
    Connection* conn = nullptr;

    string user = "username";
    string pass = "password";
    string constr = "myoracle12c.senecacollege.ca:1521/oracle12c";

    env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
    conn = env->createConnection(user, pass, constr);



    env->terminateConnection(conn);
    Environment::terminateEnvironment(env);

}
```

Here's the error I get, it's the same for Connection. How can I fix this? Which libraries do I need to import and where do I download them? I've been searching a while and would really appreciate help.

[image]

Comment: You're not including the Oracle OCCI headers. Header files is where libraries declare all their classes and other symbols needed to use the library.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Is it as simple as using an #include or must i go into the options and set paths and such?

Comment: I have downloaded the instant client, i have the files oci.dll, orannzsbb11.dll,  and oraocci11.dll. How do i use them?

Comment: Those DLL files are for distribution, not development. You need header file (file ending in `.h`) and linker library files (files ending in `.lib`). Oh, and you of course need the DLL files as well for running.

Comment: What are .sym files? I have those in the folder as well. I don't see any .lib or .h files, do u know where I could download them?

Comment: Download them from Oracle? I haven't worked with Oracle and OCCI since version 10, 15 years ago or something (and I'm very grateful for that!) so I don't know where Oracle might have put it.